# Cannot export swf file from flash cs5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I am creating an application using flash cs5.5 Here it is. Up to certain part of our work, we can not export the file into swf. There is no error provided. So i am clueless. Please help me im going to present this real soon.

Comment: I guess, that the best solution is to save .fla file and try to export .swf on the another PC. Also, it might be usefull if you publish the .fla file here and we may try to publish it on our machines.

Comment: Also you may try to install an older/newer version of Flash IDE on your computer and try to publish with it. For testing purpose you may use some trilal versions from Adobe.com

Comment: Hi@Flashist i did try to export using other pc and it did nothing. The file still couldnt be export as swf. Can you tell me how can I make it work by Flash IDE? Thank you.

Comment: @elen.ns Could you tell us what's the extension of your app ? And what happen when you use CTRL+Enter in the Flash IDE ? ...

Comment: @akmozo the extension is .swf and i havent try to CTRL+Enter in Flash IDE. I just CTRL+Enter .fla file and suddenly it didnt work well like before.

Comment: I meant the extension of your current application file, not what you want to get. Did you have an `.fla` file ? And when you are in the Flash IDE, what did you get after pressing CTRL+Enter ?

Comment: Yes. My current application file is .fla file. I dont have Flash IDE. So, I havent try to export inside Flash IDE.

Comment: But why you are talking about Flash CS5.5 ?!!!

Comment: @akmozo I am using Flash CS5.5 now. Look, i dont have any idea what is Flash IDE. You may get mad or curse me now, bcs i really noob and i am asking for help here.

Comment: Ah, OK ! Sorry. Flash CS5.5 here is your Flash IDE ( IDE = Integrated development environment ). Forget about the IDE term. When you are in your Flash CS5.5, what did you get after pressing CTRL+Enter ?

Comment: @akmozo Im sorry too for any harsh words. Seriously, i am a beginner. Please bare with me. Okay. after I pressed CTRL +Enter, nothing appears.. no errors..no popup window for the .swf file. Just, nothing.

Comment: No problem about that. Did you have this behavior only with this app or it's always the case ? Could you put a snapshot of your Flash when you are working in you Flash app ? Try to restart Flash CS5.5, create a new app, and try again ...

Comment: @akmozo this happen only to this application. I tried to create new file and export, it works well. Plus, I already restart many times. *clueless*

Comment: Could you provide that "special" application fla file ?

Comment: @akmozo sure. Wait, let me upload into dropbox and give you the link. Pleaseee wait for a while. Thank you

Comment: @akmozo i am sorry. Connection isnt good. Still uploading into my dropbox. Will mention you here once it settle. Sorry.

Comment: @akmozo hi. I am sorry, really sorry for the troubles. The connection was really bad and I was unable to upload to Dropbox. But, i try to uninstall cs5.5 and re-install with cs6. The .swf file appears, but! When I try to save the file CTRL + S, first attempt was succesful. But after that, the file cant be saved. It appears " unable tp save the document and please try to save to different name or path". I did. But still didnt manage to save.

Comment: No problem, I understand. For your file, verify that is not opened by another application, and please remove your question after that because it's no longer about programming ...

Comment: @akmozo okay. Thank you for your help.